# Different controls in ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a ItemsControl defined like so:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}">
    <ItemsControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="Big">
                     <Setter Property="Content" Value="BigStyle"/>
                </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="Small">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="SmallStyle"/>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{StaticResource RoundCornerButtonMagentaFilledBig}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PageViewModels.Count}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{StaticResource RoundCornerButtonMagentaFilledSmall}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel.Name}" Value="Home Page">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Style>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding PageViewModels.Count}" Margin="0,19"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button x:Name="NavigationButton"
                                Content="{Binding Name}"
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding }"
                                Style="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This displays me a grid of buttons based on parameter. However, I now want it to display different controls in this grid. For example, If `PageViewModesl.Count` is 2, I want to have a grid

BUTTON BUTTON

If it's 3:

BUTTON BUTTON BUTTON

But, if it's 4, I want to have:

BUTTON TEXT BUTTON TEXT

How can I put different controls in there?

Comment: You may use a DataTemplateSelector (assigned to the ItemsControl's ItemTemplateSelector property), or ItemContainerStyle Triggers like e.g. shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56057099/1136211